# Arty A7 Board question about JTAG cable

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I have an Arty A7 board with Artix-7 FPGA from Xilinx.
from the datasheet, I see that the micro-usb cable can be power up the board and also used as a jtag cable for programming the board and communication with the PC.

My question is, using the Arty A7 board, the micro-usb cable can be used both as a power source and jtag cable for the board? I can also power up the board and program the device at once using the micro USB?

Because I still don't have the compatible power source cable for this board and I'm using the micro-usb cable to power up the board, but when I trying to program my design into the FPGA, Vivado software can't identify the board.

Someone using the micro USB cable with Arty A7 board as a power source as well as jtag cable?
thanks.

Comment: which datasheet are you talking about?

Comment: I don't have that particular board but I do have Digilent's Basys 3 board, which also uses the Artix-7 (an XC7A35T.) It also has a separate provision for an external power source separate from using the micro-USB cable which serves as both power and JTAG. It also has the ability to download code to test or, alternately, to load it into a serial flash chip so that it boots it without needing to download again. And Vivado recognizes it well when using the micro-USB/JTAG/power method. (I'm not using the most recent one because I can't seem to download it. But that shouldn't matter here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your computer can supply enough power, then yes, that should work fine.  If you need more power, then there is a jumper that you can use to select the DC jack and you can power the board that way.  That jack also accepts 5V, so presumably you could make an adapter cable to USB if you want to use a USB power bank or USB power adapter.